# At what age does a minor kohen start to recite Birkat Kohanim?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minor-katan-child, chinuch-education, birchas-kohanim

[Shulchan Aruch 128:34](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.128.34?lang=bi) rules that a minor kohen performs *nesiat kapayim* (lit. 'rasing the palms', i.e. reciting the Priestly Blessing) in order to learn and become accustomed to the practice (as long as adult *kohanim* are doing so at the same time).

[Mishnah Berurah 128:123](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.128.123?lang=bi) notes that this is not at the regular age of *chinuch* (five or six years old), but rather when the child knows how to 'raise his palms' according to the custom of the *kohanim*, without giving a specific age or age range.

This seems to leave the age at which a minor *kohen* begins to perform *nesiat kapayim* somewhat flexible, depending on the development of the child in question.

However, I remember being told by my father that our family custom was that minor *kohanim* only start to perform *nesiat kapayim* during the festival before they turn thirteen.

**Are there any (written) sources available describing the practice for minor *kohanim* to only start performing *nesiat kapayim* during the festival before they turn thirteen?**

**Are there any sources describing alternative practices, starting at a different fixed point?**

(It would seem to me that starting the festival before the *kohen's* thirteenth birthday would make the most sense in communities where *nesiat kapayim* is only performed on festivals. Communities with weekly or daily *nesiat kapayim* could be expected to have a different starting point (if they have one at all).)

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35947/putting-on-tefilin-one-month-before-bar-mitzva

Comment: Observation from Jerusalem: Sefardim seem to start very young, Litvaks seem to wait until (just before?) Bar Mitzva.IIRC the Yekkes at home started a few years before Bar Mitzva.

Comment: This question seems to hinge on your objecting that this is not an objective age.

Comment: What do you mean before thirteen ?

Comment: @Shmuel I'm afraid I'm not following either of your comments. Please expand